# App crashing on particular Android version

Tags: android, crash

I am working on an Android application. when I run my App below api 16 it works fine but when it runs on a post api 16 phone it crashes. Here is a the logact log which appears when it crashes.

```
06-19 20:20:05.096    5812-5812/com.ets.medecord W/dalvikvm﹕ threadid=1: thread exiting with uncaught exception (group=0x42011898)
06-19 20:20:05.106    5812-5812/com.ets.medecord E/AndroidRuntime﹕ FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    java.lang.RuntimeException: Unable to start activity ComponentInfo{com.ets.medecord/com.ets.medecord.SignupActivity2}: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2218)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
            at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
     Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException
            at com.ets.medecord.SignupActivity2.onCreate(SignupActivity2.java:72)
            at android.app.Activity.performCreate(Activity.java:5135)
            at android.app.Instrumentation.callActivityOnCreate(Instrumentation.java:1087)
            at com.lbe.security.service.core.client.b.x.callActivityOnCreate(Unknown Source)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.performLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2182)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.handleLaunchActivity(ActivityThread.java:2268)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.access$600(ActivityThread.java:148)
            at android.app.ActivityThread$H.handleMessage(ActivityThread.java:1263)
            at android.os.Handler.dispatchMessage(Handler.java:99)
            at android.os.Looper.loop(Looper.java:137)
            at android.app.ActivityThread.main(ActivityThread.java:5162)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
            at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:525)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit$MethodAndArgsCaller.run(ZygoteInit.java:756)
            at com.android.internal.os.ZygoteInit.main(ZygoteInit.java:572)
            at miui.dexspy.DexspyInstaller.main(DexspyInstaller.java:171)
            at dalvik.system.NativeStart.main(Native Method)
```

To see code of the activity you can checkout this gist https://gist.github.com/darthvish/873dc292c841e5c86312

Comment: clean your project and run again.

Comment: Please are you able to post the code of SignupActivity2.java

Comment: @RajanBhavsar yes I am updating my question.

Comment: the problem is here  com.ets.medecord.SignupActivity2.onCreate(SignupActivity2.java:72)

Comment: post your activity code

Comment: @Kartheek you can found complete code at https://gist.github.com/darthvish/873dc292c841e5c86312

Comment: Do you have a different version of your layout file, activity_signup2.xml for API 16?  It looks like button btn2_signup_complete may not exist in the API 16 layout.

Comment: @qbix No I don't have different layout for API 16

Comment: In your github code, line 72 is "handler = new Handler()".  Is that correct?  I don't understand how that could be causing a null pointer exception.

Comment: @qbix actually I make some changes in code so order of code changed little bit, actual line when I note this log is different. I posting code of where was line 72

Comment: `btnSignupComplete.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() `

Comment: Right. So btnSignupComplete is null.  It was not found in your layout.  Look at "activity_signup2.xml" and figure it why ID "btn_signup2_complete" is not there.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/81242/discussion-between-darth-vish-and-qbix).

Answer (score 0):

As you are using some deprecated features, so it may not supported for some API levels. For this you can check the api level as well as version before using the deprecated features using if condition. For example :

```
if(Build.VERSION.RELEASE.equals("4.4.4")) {
            //Do somthing
}
```